nodejs decryption Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data
i am getting below error:
Error: Unsupported state or unable to authenticate data
at Decipheriv.final
here is my code to encrypt (in reactjs):
async function encryptJsonData(jsonData, secretKey) {
    const encoder = new TextEncoder();
    const data = encoder.encode(JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    const key = await window.crypto.subtle.importKey(
        "raw",
        encoder.encode(secretKey.slice(0, 32)),
        { name: "AES-GCM", length: 256 },
        false,
        ["encrypt"]
    );
    const iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
    const encrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        { name: "AES-GCM", iv },
        key,
        data
    );
    return {
        iv: Array.from(iv),
        data: Array.from(new Uint8Array(encrypted)),
    };
}

code to decrypt in nodejs:
const crypto = require('crypto');

const decryptJsonData = async (encryptedData, secretKey) => {
    const { iv, data } = encryptedData;
    const key = crypto.createSecretKey(Buffer.from(secretKey), 'utf-8');
    
    const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, Buffer.from(iv));

    let decrypted = decipher.update(Buffer.from(data));
    decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);

    return JSON.parse(decrypted.toString());
}

module.exports = decryptJsonData

I am tried several ways to solve the error but failed, i used auth_tags also bit nothing is working. Please help !!!
I have tried to use auth_tags, and more things but nothing worked.

The WebCrypto API implicitly concatenates ciphertext and authentication tag (ciphertext | 16 bytes tag), while the crypto module of NodeJS processes both individually.
For this reason, ciphertext and tag must first be separated during decryption on the NodeJS side. The tag must be set explicitly with setAuthTag(). This must happen somewhere between the creation of the decipher instance and the final() call:
var dataBuf = Buffer.from(data);                                                 // separate ciphertetxt and tag
var ciphertext = dataBuf.subarray(0, -16);
var tag = dataBuf.subarray(-16);
...
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-gcm', key, Buffer.from(iv));
decipher.setAuthTag(tag);                                                        // pass tag
let decrypted = decipher.update(ciphertext);                                     // pass ciphertext
decrypted = Buffer.concat([decrypted, decipher.final()]);


Security: Note that (due to the generally lower entropy of passwords) a password should not be used directly as encryption key, but that the actual key should be derived from the password using a reliable key derivation function (at least PBKDF2).

Or, recent nodejs also supports the webcrypto API directly

Provided you prefer the WebCrypto API over the crypto-module on NodeJS (the latter offers significantly more functionality and is less cumbersome).
